# How to parse belowJSON in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to parse the response JSON and get summary and action each time and form a separate object with that.

```
{
"issues": [
    {
    "fields":
        {
        "summary": "This is summary",
        "action": "Start"
        }
    }, {
    "fields":
        {
        "summary": "Second summary",
        "action": "Stop"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: expected output please

Comment: "summary": "Second summary",
 "action": "Stop"

Comment: "summary": "This is summary",
 "action": "Start"

Comment: need individual output in a stringmessage to pass to a consumer one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Issues class and Fields class. Below is a snippet for reference,

```
public class Issues {

   private List<Fields> fields;

   // Getters and Setters

}


public class Fields {

   private String summary;

   private String action;

   // Getters and Setters

}
```

You can map the response to the Issues object and go ahead iterating the fields List to fetch the summary and action out of it.

Comment: My response mentioned above list is in resplist, can you provide me the exact snippet to iterate.

Comment: you can use Java Streams to iterate fields to fetch summary and action to pass to customer one by one,  getFileds from the Issues Object and iterate as below, fields.stream().forEach((x) -> // pass summary & action to customer);